# Implement a GridView.Count with non scrollable first row and column

Tags: flutter, gridview

So I am implementing sort of a data table in flutter. it shows data based on time in days in rows and some other variant in columns. so naturally, first row is name of the days, and then in first column are values of the other variant. What properties of GridView.count can I use to make first row and column stay fixed when scrolling the grid. so that you can always see the data variants in screen.
I have gone over all properties of GridView.count but I can't find anything.

PS:  I don't want to change to something else Like GridView.builder..... because the code is too far gone with how it renders the dynamic data in the rest of rows and columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Use data table instead of Grid

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html.

Comment: please read the PS.